# Barcode string to bitmap

Tags: c#, zxing

I have function that prints barcode to bitmap:

```
public void drawQr()
        {
            IBarcodeWriter writer = new BarcodeWriter
            {
                Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
                Options = new QrCodeEncodingOptions
                {
                    Width = 60,
                    Height = 60
                }
            };

            barcodeBitmap = writer.Write(SerialTextBox.Text);
            pictureBox1.Image = barcodeBitmap;
        }
```

This function does not work with new version of Zxing because there in no more `IBarcodeWriter.Write` method. How to get barcode bitmap from string in new `ZXing` version?

Comment: Has it been changed to `QRCodeWriter`? In the [documentation](https://zxing.github.io/zxing/apidocs/), choose the `com.google.zxing` package and look for *`writer`* in the list of interfaces.